# GetFileAttributesExW() or FileTimeToSystemTime() doesn't work in Release, when works in Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, release, visual-studio-debugging

I use `GetFileAttributesExW()` to get the date for file. In **DEBUG** mode (Visual Studio 2012), everything works fine, I get e.g. *"2013-05-10"*. But when I change target to **RELEASE**, the date is **corrupted** (I get at the end of my function the string e.g. *"1678-09-08"*).

The full code:

```
bool Registry::fileDate(std::wstring pathString, std::string &dateOut)
{
    if (pathString.size() == 0)
        return false;

    if (pathString[0] == '\"')
    {
        pathString = pathString.erase(0, 1);
    }

    if (pathString[pathString.size()-1] == '\"')
    {
        pathString = pathString.erase(pathString.size()-1, 1);
    }

    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t found = pathString.find('\"', pos);
    if (found > 0 && found != std::string::npos)
    {
        pathString = pathString.substr(0, found);
    }

    std::wstring filePath = pathString;

    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileData;
    GetFileAttributesExW(filePath.c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &fileData);
    SYSTEMTIME systemTime;

    bool res = FileTimeToSystemTime(&fileData.ftCreationTime, &systemTime);
    if (res)
    {
        char buf[40] = {0};
        for(int i=0; i<40; i++) //to be even more certain that no trash will get here
            buf[i] = ' ';
        sprintf(buf,"%04d-%02d-%02d",
                systemTime.wYear, systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wDay);
        dateOut = buf+'\0';
    }
    else
    {
        //show error's window, i'm sure it DOESN'T occur, both in DEBUG and RELEASE
    }
}
```

I'm aware that in **RELEASE** some optimizations have to be done. That optimizations and my mistake (which I cannot see) together must result in corrupted date.

To the function go strings like:

```
L"\"C:\\Program Files\\File\\setup.exe\" /uninstall PROPLUS /dll OSETUP.DLL"
```

Which in **DEBUG**, are converted in first lines of my function to:

```
L"C:\\Program Files\\File\\setup.exe"
```

**Edit:** 
(Thx to  Raymond Chen's comment)

Now I know that in RELEASE, `GetFileAttributesExW()` returns **FALSE**, so maybe somehow that part works in **DEBUG** and doesn't work in **RELEASE** (it should get rid of extra *"* and */params* from path):

```
if(pathString.size() == 0)
    return false;

if(pathString[0] == '\"'){
    pathString = pathString.erase(0, 1);
}

if(pathString[pathString.size()-1] == '\"'){
    pathString = pathString.erase(pathString.size()-1, 1);
}

size_t pos = 0;
size_t found = pathString.find('\"', pos);
if (found > 0 && found != std::string::npos)
{
    pathString = pathString.substr(0, found);
}

std::wstring filePath = pathString;
```

Comment: Try using TCHAR instead of the char. It is possible that the RELEASE mode in Unicode and DEBUG mode is not.

Comment: I tried it, and also checked that both RELEASE and DEBUG have Unicode set. When I put "systemTime.wYear = 1410;" before sprintf, it produces the "1410-09-08" date.

Comment: What is `dateOut`? If it is a `char*` then you are using memory (`buf`) after it is freed. You also did not check the return value of `GetFileAttributesExW`. Perhaps the `filePath` is not valid in RELEASE mode. Step through the code checking all variables after each line and checking all return values.

Comment: Thx for pointing about dateOut, and GetFileAttributesExW result, that made me to focus on strings that are processed, I updated my question.

Comment: Are you getting identical values for filePath in debug and release? When GetFileAttributesExW returns false what is GetLastError reporting?

Comment: Now that your know that the problem is in the calculation of `pathString`, you can debug your code that calculates `pathString`.